# Unix - If file arguments already have

Tags: unix, if-statement, sh, executable

```
###Takes filenames as arguments and makes those executable
#create file variable
file=$*
chmod 755 $file
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
echo permission change suceeded
else
echo permission change failed
exit 0
fi
```

This is my current code - I'm wanting to add an extra echo which will be "already got executable permission" - how would i add a check onto this to check that if it has executable permission or not

Comment: `man [` and search for `exec`.

Comment: You should be using `"$@"` instead of `$*`; and assigning to `file` will wreck things.  Also, the `if` is contorted.  Just `if chmod 755 "$@"; then`... would work better and also be simpler and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -x "$file" ]; then
   echo "already got executable permission"
else
    ....
fi
```

Check

```
help test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perm="$(stat -c "%a" $file)" 
if [$perm -eq 755]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

Comment: This is a syntax error.  You need whitespace inside the `[` ... `]`.

Comment: And also, if the file is 775, it is already executable, but with additional permissions.